# Shell Environment in emacs sessions

Tags: shell, environment

I noticed that terminal-based emacs and GUI emacs seems to work differently in terms of shell environment, even if they are started in the same terminal session.

For example, I'm working with [roslisp](http://wiki.ros.org/roslisp/Overview) right now, in which I start emacs, and load my package with a command which includes calling a shell command `rospack` that search for my package.

If I'm doing it from a GUI emacs started from a properly configured shell session(that is, I could use `rospack` to find my package from the shell session), the command called inside emacs wouldn't be able to find my package. If I call `rospack find my_package` in `eshell`, the same output is produced; however if I call it in `term`, it could find my package sucessfully

If I'm doing it from a terminal-based emacs started in the very same shell session, the command called inside emacs would be able to find my package.

However, as tested, all environment variables should be inherited in both. If I `export NEW_ENV=foo` in the shell session just before starting both, `getenv` would be able to find `NEW_ENV` with value `foo`.

due to this behaviour, I now work primarily with a terminal-based emacs server and `emacsclient -c` for GUI.

The only literature I find relevent as of now is [this blog from XahLee](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/emacs_env_var_paths.html), which does not say anything on this behaviour. I wonder if there's anything different in how GUI emacs and terminal-based emacs interact with shell that accounts for this behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps this is not an Emacs feature/bug.  In a graphical interface, applications inherit environment variables in a different way than you might think.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Just to really confirm: When you say "If I'm doing it from a GUI emacs started from a properly configured shell session" you definitely mean that you're starting your GUI Emacs by executing the command `emacs` in that shell, yes?  You're not running it using a desktop icon or anything like that?  And you're not running `emacsclient` and connecting to a server that wasn't started from your shell?  (Or inadvertently using an alias which does something like that?)  A GUI `emacs` and a terminal `emacs -nw` started from the same shell *should* inherit the same environment.

Comment: Before you start the emacs gui, run `type emacs` in your shell. This will tell you if it is an alias, function, script or the emacs program itself.

Comment: @Trevoke At that time it was Ubuntu Studio 22.04.

Comment: @phils yes, I did `emacs` in the shell session, `Ctrl-c` in the same session to shut down, then `emacs -nw` in the very same session.